# Why is my code returning an incorrect value?

Tags: c

I'm very new to C and I am trying to figure out why my code is returning an incorrect value.

```
int main()
{


    printf("Welcome to my number generator! \n");
    printf("What is the first number in the range? \n");
    int rng1 = scanf("%d", &rng1);
    printf("What is the second number in the range? \n");
    int rng2 = scanf("%d", &rng2);
    printf("What would increment would you like to go up in? \n");
    int inc = scanf("%d", &inc);

    do
        {
        printf("%d\n"rng1);
        rng1 += inc;
        }
    while(rng1 != rng2);
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

From this code I expect a list of number between the first range and the second range going up in a certain number, but instead I get a value of 1. What am I doing wrong? 
P.S. I tried to 'debug' it and found that when I used:

```
if(isalpha(rng1));
    printf("I am a String...")
if(isdigit(rng1))
    printf("I am a Digit")
```

It returned, "I am a String...".

Thanks!

Comment: Those tests are *useless* (sorry. Nice try though.) Find a description of `scanf` ... and read what its *return* value is.

Comment: FYI: `if(isalpha(rng1));` shouldn't have a semicolon after the if statement - the `printf` will always run since you "ended" that if condition with the semicolon.

Comment: scanf returns number of successfully initialized variables, therefore each one of yours returns 1 (if you gice it a valid input - number)

you should do it like this: `int rng1; scanf("%d", &rng1);`

Comment: (And those tests are useless -- even when corrected -- because they will tell you if a number represents a digit `0..9` or alphabetic character when parsed as a character. You don't want to or need to parse them as characters, so ...)

Comment: You *should* check the return from `scanf()` (to make sure the field was assigned), but *should not* assign its return back the the variable you're trying to read.

Comment: digits are in the range 0x30 through 0x39.  however the content of rng1 will be in integer.    Note isdigit(x) is expecting a char not an int.  with the compiler warnings enabled, the compiler would have issued a warning about incorrect passed parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I am starting to see where I went wrong and made error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already assigning the input value to the variables `rng1`, `rng2` and `inc` by calling `scanf` and also `scanf` returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. Therefore it is not correct to assign the return value of `scanf` to these variables. Just use the return value for the number of inputs. You should read value `1`, because you want to read only one value for each `scanf`. Moreover, you can also check the input values in order to detect whether the entered value is valid or not.

Besides that, I would like to make a few modifications on your code. Especially your `do{...}while();` loop may be run indefinitely due to the `!=` operator. Please see the comments in the code below.

```
int main()
{
    /* Declare the variables and do not assign the return value of scanf */
    int rng1, rng2, inc;
    printf("Welcome to my number generator! \n");
    printf("What is the first number in the range? \n");
    /* repeat this check condition for each scanf, exit( EXIT_FAILURE ) requires #include <stdlib.h>*/

    if (1 != scanf("%d", &rng1)) {
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    printf("What is the second number in the range? \n");
    scanf("%d", &rng2);
    printf("What would increment would you like to go up in? \n");
    scanf("%d", &inc);

    do
    {
        printf("%d\n",rng1);
        rng1 += inc;
    }
    /* Use <= instead of != and think about the case for rng1 is 1 rng2 is 5 and inc is 3, can you detect the end of the loop by adding 3 to the starting point 1 ? */
    while(rng1 <= rng2);

    /* Remove the `}` here */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it seems to work well now. So the problem was that I was overwriting the values of the variables rather than reading the return of scanf and setting that to the value of the variable?

Comment: For the strange value problem, yes. However, you should also check while(rng1 <= rng2); in your original code.

Answer (score 1):

When you're passing the address of your variable (using the `&` operator), you're allowing `scanf` to write the scanned value to your variable. The return value of `scanf` is *not* the value you're looking for (it's something else).

So, when you're assigning the return value of `scanf` to your variable, you're overwriting the correct value it already has. This should work:

```
int rng1;
scanf("%d", &rng1);
```

Comment: But you should check the return value to make sure you read the correct number of items.

Comment: So by using the '=' sign I was over-writing the value of 'int rng1' with a different result rather than the user input?

Comment: @Dinar Yes. Others have described what the return value of `scanf` actually is. You may have uses for that result or you may choose to ignore it for now, but in any case you shouldn't overwrite the variable where `scanf` has already put the user input.

Answer (score 1):

The returned value of `scanf()` should always be checked to assure successful operation. 
The format string should (almost) always contain a leading space ' '
so an left over white space (like newlines) are skipped over/consumed
Therefore, the code should be more like:

```
int rng1;
if( 1 != scanf(" %d", &rng1) ) 
{ // then, scanf failed
    perror( "scanf for rng1 failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, scanf for rng1 successful
```

Answer (score 0):

AS above two comment explained scnaf() has return value just to check successful operation. However the value you need to read is there as second argument.
I can also see bracket mismatch in the code.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Welcome to my number generator! \n");
    printf("What is the first number in the range? \n");
    int rng1;
    int t = scanf("%d", &rng1);                 // First scanned value stored in rng1 variable
    printf("What is the second number in the range? \n");
    int rng2;
    int t1 = scanf("%d", &rng2);                    // Second scanned value stored in rng2 variable
    printf("What would increment would you like to go up in? \n");
    int inc;
    int t2 = scanf("%d", &inc);                 // Third scanned value stored in inc variable

    do
    {
        printf("%d\n",rng1);
        rng1 += inc;
    }
    while(rng1 <= rng2);             // repeat until rng1 reaches value of rng2 

    return 0;
}
```

Here using temporary variables t,t1 and t2 you may verify whether scanning of the values are done successfully or not.